# Understanding the Triangular Wave Function

Tags: probability

I posted a question ([Forcing a Brownian Motion to Stay Between Two Values?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4825347/forcing-a-brownian-motion-to-stay-between-two-values)) where I was interested in learning about if a Brownian Motion can be defined in such a way, such that it never goes below $0$ and never goes above $1$.

In the previous question ([Forcing a Brownian Motion to Stay Between Two Values?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4825347/forcing-a-brownian-motion-to-stay-between-two-values)), I was shown that for the range $(0,1)$, apparently this can be done with the "Triangular Wave Function".

**My Problem:** I am interested in knowing if this approach (i.e. Triangular Wave Function)  or some other approach can be used to define a Brownian Motion, such that the Brownian Motion will always stay between some arbitrary range of $(a,b)$.

According to this Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflected_Brownian_motion), the principle of Reflection can be used to define such a Brownian Motion:

*A* $d$*-dimensional reflected Brownian motion* $Z$ *is a stochastic process on* $\mathbb{R}^d_+$ *uniquely defined by:*

- *a* $d$-*dimensional drift vector* $\mu$,
- *a* $d \times d$ *non-singular covariance matrix* $\Sigma$
- *a* $d \times d$ *reflection matrix* $R$.

*Where*:

- $X(t)$ *is an unconstrained Brownian motion with drift $\mu$ and variance* $\Sigma$
- $Z(t) = X(t) + R Y(t)$

*Such that:* $Y(t)$ *a* $d$-*dimensional vector where:*

- $Y$ *is continuous and non-decreasing with* $Y(0) = 0$,
- $Y_j$ *only increases at times for which* $Z_j = 0$ for $j = 1,2,...,d$,
- $Z(t) \in \mathbb{R}^d_+$, $t \geq 0$.

**My Question:** From the above text, it seems like $Z(t) = X(t) + R Y(t)$ is the general form for a "constrained" (i.e. reflected) Brownian Motion - however, within this formulation, I am not sure which boundaries (i.e. values of a,b) this Brownian Motion will be contained within. Furthermore, I am not sure how the matrix $R$ needs to be defined such that the Brownian Motion lies between $(a,b)$.

**Can someone please show me how I can fully mathematically define a 1 dimensional Brownian Motion to only assume values between $(a,b)$?**

Thanks!